# Problems with jQuery hover in IE

Tags: jquery, css, windows, internet-explorer, webcam

I've recently made a webcam application. See it here: http://kennipoke.dk/nickelodeon/da/docs/webcam.php

At the top is 4 helmets which when clicked will add ?helmet=X to the URI..

Now above the actual webcam screen i want the selected helmet to appear with some transparency so you can see your own face through it.

The image should only appear when you hover the shoot button.

Now i got all of this working except in IE!!!!!!

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="camera">
    <div id="screen-frame<?php echo $helmet ?>"></div>
    <div id="screen"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
         <div class="buttonPane">
           <a id="shootButton" href="" class="blueButton btn btn-info">Hold musen over denne knap og tag et billede</a>
         </div>
         <div class="buttonPane hidden">
               <a id="cancelButton" href="" class="blueButton btn btn-danger">Tag et nyt</a> <a id="uploadButton" href="" class="greenButton btn btn-info">Videre</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <span class="settings"></span>
</div>
```

Of course $helmet is the value of the URI

```
$('#shootButton').mouseover(function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
});
$('#shootButton').mouseout(function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
```

Im not that experienced with jQuery, so i made four copies of this script. One for each #screen-frameX

And heres the CSS:

```
#camera{
    background:url('../img/cam_bg.jpg') repeat-y;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
    height:370px;
    width:520px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    margin: 130px 30px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

#screen{
    width:520px;
    height:370px;
    background:#ccc;
    line-height: 360px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#666;
}

#screen-frame1 {
    background: url("../img/overlay/transparent/helmet-t-1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#screen-frame2 {
    background: url("../img/overlay/transparent/helmet-t-2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#screen-frame3 {
    background: url("../img/overlay/transparent/helmet-t-3.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#screen-frame4 {
    background: url("../img/overlay/transparent/helmet-t-4.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 520px;
    z-index: 10;
}


.hide {
    height:0;
}

.show {
    height:370px;
}
```

Can anyone spot any problems that should cause this to malfunction in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the normal hover function?

```
$('#shootButton').hover(function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
}, function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
});
```

---

EDIT:

Try the following CSS for your `show` and `hide` classes:

```
.show {
   display: block;
   height: 370px;
}
.hide {
   display: none;
   height: 0px;
}
```

You might not even need to change the `height` property, this should do the trick, also in IE.

Comment: Hey Hidde

Thanks for your answer, just tried and it made no difference, unfortunatly.

I realised that this is not only IE but also Firefox on windows, though Firefix on a Mac works fine.

Comment: Hey Hidde

Just tried that, i didnt make a difference.

I just tried debugging in IE9 and i can see that jQuery is not changing the css class on #screen-frame?

Comment: Do you have the same problem using mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead of mouseover() and mouseout()?

Comment: Hey carpii.

I just tried adding both hover, mouseover and mouseenter. Still the classes wont change on a Windows pc.

Comment: It seems the jQuery is functioning now, but still i cent see the image because the flash window for the webcam is always staying on top on a windows computer.. Does anyone know if this can be overuled?

Comment: Did you try a z-index? On both the flash and the image elements?

Comment: Yeah, i tried to define z-index's on both #screen-frame, #screen and #camera.

As long as i am on Windows, the webcam application will stay on top..

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, your contents are being dynamically loaded? Try using .live rather than just single hover.

```
$('#shootButton').live('hover', function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
}, function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('#shootButton').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
});
$('#shootButton').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#screen-frame1').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
```